# Transfer files without destination access

Tags: windows-server-2003, batch-file, file-transfer, vbscript

HI All,

I have a issue where I want to create a script (VB or Batch file) that when a user runs the script it will copy files from Folder1 to Folder2.

Here's the rub.

I don't want the users to have access to Folder2, I need them to run the scipt so they can't move files in manually and it does a bit of logging as well.

I have two ideas but don't know how feasible they are:

1. The user calls the script but it runs under different permissions. 
     How would I do this without the user seeing the account details.
2. The user runs a scipt that runs a scheduled job on the server. 
     The scheduled job would then run under different privileges but the users don't 
     have access to the server so there may be an issue running a scheduled task.

Any other ideas would be grateful.

THanks in advance

JoeOD

Answer (score 1):

Folder2 may be shared with deny access to users, and the script mounts the share with custom credentials move files than disconnect the share.

There a trick for hiding network mapped drives on windows with the *NoDrives* dword at *HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer*.

PS: You can compile your .bat script with bat2exe to avoir users seeing the file content. AutoIT script may do the job also.

EDIT: See [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;179221&x=19&y=13) for configuring the NoDrives Dword Value.